# onClick doesn't render new react component.

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react world and I have line like this:

```
<Button onClick={() => console.log("hello")}>Button</Button>
```

and on click you will get `hello` printed on the console. Now change the line to:

```
<Button onClick={() => <NewComponent />}>Button</Button>
```

now on click on the button, I expect the `NewComponent` to be rendered. But it doesn't.

I'm not sure, why that is the case. Note that I have the above code in the `render` method.

Comment: That's just not how it works. Where would you expect the component to render?

Comment: But where? Above the button? Below the button? Inside the button? *Inside the `onClick` attribute?* Somewhere else? Currently your click handler is something like `function() { React.createElement(...); }`. It doesn't do anything with the element that was created.

Comment: @FelixKling: Oh now it make sense, so we need to do something like `React.render` and give the area in which need to be renderd

Comment: Right. But your component should probably just have state and render the component next to the button after the button was clicked.

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks now it make sense, you can provide the answer I can accept.

Comment: i am having the same problem. t tried the solution below,yet its not working for me. can you please have a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158143/rendering-react-components-on-click/42158375#42158375

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You probably want to have a stateful component that shows the other component next to the button after it was clicked. All you need to do is track whether the button was clicked:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showComponent: false,
    };
    this._onButtonClick = this._onButtonClick.bind(this);
  }

  _onButtonClick() {
    this.setState({
      showComponent: true,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this._onButtonClick}>Button</Button>
        {this.state.showComponent ?
           <NewComponent /> :
           null
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi.what if i want to load only  NewComponent  on the same page overwriting all the other components without using react router?

Comment: @MustafaMuawia: No.

Comment: For some reason, it shows me this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'onButtonClick' of undefined

Comment: @AbhirajshriWinsome: You are likely accessing `this.onButtonClick` in a function who's `this` value does not  point to the component instance.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/brianswisher/pen/qOwXYj?editors=101) to show it in action.

HTML

```
<div id="root">loading...</div>
```

JSX

```
class NewComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div {...this.props}>
        new component
      </div>
    );
  }  
}

class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button {...this.props}>
        click
      </button>
    );
  }  
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      clicked: false
    };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      clicked: true
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick} />
        {this.state.clicked ? <NewComponent /> : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
};

React.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: A pen never helped so much. I'm starting to get the conditional rendering issue about React :) thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Use instead:
 `{this.state.clicked && <NewComponent />}`

Answer (score 2):

you can use **withRouter()** of **react-router-dom**. When we use `<Route path='/path' component={newComponent} />` react-router-dom passes three props **"history,location and match"** , you can use **push()** function of history props in your onClick just by passing your whole component in **withRouter()** as:

JSX

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom' ;
import Button from 'buttonFolder/button.component';
const yourComponent = ({history}) => {

return (
       <Button onClick{() => history.push.('/path')}> New componentPage </Button>
)};

export default withRouter(yourComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set state to track visibility of the component.  Default it to false, and onclick set state to true.  In your render do something like 
{this.state.visible ?  : null}