# React: Render JSX repeatedly with multiple onClicks

Tags: html, reactjs

[I followed this stackoverflow answer however i want to know how i can modify this to have it render jsx again & again with multiple clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33840150/onclick-doesnt-render-new-react-component)

Answer (score 0):

here's a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/brianswisher/pen/qOwXYj?editors=101) to show it in action

```js
class NewComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div {...this.props}>
        new component
      </div>
    );
  }  
}

class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button {...this.props}>
        click
      </button>
    );
  }  
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    this.state = {
      clicked: false
    };
    
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      clicked: true
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick} />
        {this.state.clicked ? <NewComponent /> : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">loading...</div>
```