# firing onClick handler when click on component inside it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

when i click on button section its working fine , but the problem is when i click on Component section inside button then my function not firing

```
this.resetStates = this.resetStates.bind(this) ;

<button onClick={this.resetStates}>
    <NumberFormat/>
</button>
```

Comment: what is `this.resetStates`? How is it defined?

Comment: So your desired outcome is to have the function fire when you click on the NumberFormat component?

Comment: possible duplication / helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33840150/onclick-doesnt-render-new-react-component

Comment: add code of <NumberFormat/> component

Comment: resetStates using setStates method to set new value of state

Comment: i want to fire function when user clicks on numberFormat Component

Answer (score 0):

I use a CSS lot of the time with similar problems in svg. It might help you here too. You can put pointer-events: none  to the inner component. This way the inner component is not clickable and every click event come to the outer button component.
For example:

```
<button onClick={this.resetStates}>
  <div style={{pointerEvents: 'none'}}>
     <NumberFormat/>
  </div>
</button>
```

Is it helping you?